# I can't figure out the require in ruby

Tags: ruby, require

I'm new to Ruby

MakModule.rb

```
module Display
  class Multiply
    def Multiply.mul(first, second)
      return first * second
    end
  end
end
```

MakRequire1.rb

```
require "Display"
puts Multiply.mul 5,6
```

MakRequire2.rb

```
require "MakModule.rb"
puts Multiply.mul 5,6
```

both file give me the error below

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- makRequire (LoadError)
```

How should I correct my code?

Comment: You could start by posting the *actual* code that produces the error, since it is absolutely 100% impossible that the code you posted here will generate that error message.

Comment: Also, what version of Ruby are you using, as that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simply impossible that the code you posted here generates that error message. The error message says that you tried to `require` a file named `makRequire`, but that filename doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted.

Without the actual code that is generating the actual error, it is impossible to answer your question. However, here are a few general tips:

Whenever the computer tells you that it cannot find something, in 99% of the cases, the problem is that the thing the computer tells it couldn't find isn't actually there.

So, in this case, the computer tells you that it cannot find a file named `makRequire.rb`, and the most likely explanation for that is that `makRequire.rb` doesn't actually exist. So, the first thing you need to check is: *does* `makRequire.rb` (note the capitalization and the file extension) actually exist? Because if it doesn't exist, then the reason why the computer cannot find it, should be rather obvious.

In 99% of the *rest* of the cases, the problem is that the thing the computer is looking for *does* exist, but the computer is looking in the wrong place. So, after you have verified that `makRequire.rb` actually *does* exist, you need to make sure that the directory the file is in, is in Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`, and if it isn't, you need to add that directory to Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`. Alternatively, if you want to `require` the file relative to the path of the file that is doing the requiring, you need to use `require_relative` instead of `require`.

The third thing to check for, is whether the user who own the `ruby` process has sufficient privileges to access the file `makRequire.rb`, the directory it is in and all of its parent directories.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer,

Comment: This explanation shouldn't take more then 3-4 lines and be straight to the point.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'MarkModule')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `require './MakModule'`, because the `.` is the current directory.

Comment: Good to hear. The `./` works in lots of places, including bash and html links.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'MakModule'
```

Comment: The OP is already doing that. [`require`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005941) allows the use of the extension, or will supply several different values for the extension if it isn't provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can require a file that is in the same directory. To use a module you would typically `include` the module inside a class definition. So you would never require `Display`, you would require the file that contains `Display` (without the .rb extension, usually).

Comment: I think in 1.9, `require` 'requires' an absolute path.

Comment: I run 1.9. It does not require an absolute path... I can always require files in the same folder with just `require 'filename'`